# Splunk Cloud HEC endpoint address do not resolve

Tags: splunk, splunk-hec

I have just created a Splunk Cloud trial account.

I can access perfectly to console with an URL in the form https://prd-p-naaaa.splunkcloud.com where naaaa is a digit and 4 letters.

I have configured an HEC token following the instructions [here](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/8.2.2203/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector#Configure_HTTP_Event_Collector_on_Splunk_Cloud_Platform)

But this do not shown the endpoints to use. I have checked the docs in [here](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.0/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector), and I assume that my HEC endpoint is:

https://http-inputs-prd-p-naaaa.splunkcloud.com

But this address is not DNS resolved.

I have also tried other alternatives, as dot instead minus

https://http-inputs.prd-p-naaaa.splunkcloud.com

Any comment or suggestion will be welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:

In Splunk Cloud Trial the HEC endpoint is in the same host (without prefix) and port 8088.

So, the URL is, in my case,

https://prd-p-naaaa.splunkcloud.com:8088/services/collector

Comment: It seems they are using self signed certificates on that url now (maybe it was the case before as well)

Answer (score 0):

Try `https://http-inputs-prd-p-naaaa.splunkcloud.com:443`.  The "http-inputs" part does not change if you use a secure connection.

Comment: Thank you for checking, but I was already using http-... (my fault when transcrypt). The problem is with DNS resolving. It does resolve http-inputs-prd-p-naaaa.splunkcloud.com. And again, thank you for checking!!! (I have corrected my question to set http-inputs)